# Is it possible to run as administrator only through code

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, winapi, process, uac

OS: Windows
Language: C

I have a requirement such as , I should not change the exe's manifest or the exe file's properties to run it as administrator.  Is there any chance in doing my requirement with createprocess/createprocessasuser api. This can be done through shellexecute api, However I need to create my process in suspended state. this can only be done by createprocess or createprocessasuser api.
It would be grateful,If some one can guide me in running a program as administrator through these api.

Comment: Thinking out loud, but I think it is possible to request permission elevation using the UAC (User Account Control) feature of Win 7 and Vista. There is most likely a Win32 API for this.

Comment: So let me get this straight. You have decided to *avoid* using the mechanisms that are explicitly documented to address your requirements, and are hoping that some other completely unrelated alternative exists that just happens to solve your problem?

Comment: @Cody Gray: to me the last sentence implies that he wants to use exactly one of these documented APIs.

Comment: @tomasmcguinness: he named one of the official APIs for that. UAC only works at the process boundaries. Meaning you have to create a new elevated process, rather than elevating your existing one.

Comment: are you alright with the UAC elevation dialog being shown and the user having to enter admin credentials, or consent if the user is an admin?

Comment: @David: I am happy with the UAC elevation dialog which asks to enter password. But Is there a chance to do it via createprocess or createprocessasuser api

Comment: @Beetles The only way to gain elevated rights is to show the UAC dialog. If you could just take elevated rights by calling the right function then UAc would be rather pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're out of luck. ShellExecute will launch the second app elevated either because it has a manifest or because you use the `runas` verb. CreateProcess will not.

Perhaps you can use CreateProcess to launch your suspended second app and then that can use ShellExecute to launch the elevated third app that actually does the privileged action? Alternatively you could run the whole suite of apps elevated, or move the functionality into a service which is UAC-exempt.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest solution would be to route the process you're trying to launch though `runas /user:administrator "yourprocess.exe"` or supply the `runas` string literal to the second parameter of `ShellExecute`. This seems to be an undocumented feature tough.

```
ShellExecute(
    NULL,
    _T("runas"),
    _T("notepad.exe"),
    _T(""),    // params
    NULL,        // directory
    SW_SHOW
);
```

Comment: thanks mate.  I have worked out in shellexecute and which will not help me. So i have mentioned in my question that i am looking for a chance to do it via createprocess or createprocessasuser api

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible because **it would violate the whole purpose** of such a restriction!

Allowing it, even for "good intentions", still constitutes a security breach.

> Blockquote Oh come on. Two things: you completely underestimate the bad guys (many of them are quite smart and would not ask such a question), it seems. And also just because someone wants to do "hacky" things doesn't mean it's for malicious purposes. – STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED

Comment: I am just making it clear that i am not asking to skip the administrator authentication. I just want a normal exe to be executed with administrator privilege through (Create process or createprocessasuser API). I am happy in supplying the credetials on execution.

Comment: @Beetles You don't need to change the manifest (assuming the exe does not have one) you can just add one to the directory and windows should use that if configured properly for the user.